# ui.item.parent() doesn't return ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using sortable plugin of jQuery UI. This is my code:

```
   $(element).sortable({
        handle: ".handle",
        placeholder: "drophover",
        connectWith: '.day ul',
        helper: "clone",
        scroll: false,
        revert: 100,
 receive: function (event, ui) {
    //ui.item.parent doesn't return ul in console.log. However ui.item outputs li in //console.log
});
```

**Edit:**

If I do `$(ui.item).parent()`, it still doesn't work. Attached is the image from my console.log

[image]

Please see that `ul` is not outputted and my length is `0`.

**2nd Edit:** It looks like we can't get parent inside 'receive' event of sortable. If I try it inside update, it works.

Comment: see my answer below. to get the parent, use `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `receive` callback, just use `this`. It is equal to the container you dropped it in. In jQuery form it would simply be `$(this)`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
ui.item.parent
```

Try with jQuery function:

```
$(ui.item).parent()
```

You were using `parent` but there is no *property* named like that in jQuery. There is function though [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).